# Which LinQ syntax?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

When searching for a word in the search field I shall be enable to find a word for instance "cookies" by typing "Coo" or "oOk". what LinQ syntax do I need to create this functionality?

Beside, the functionality should take account to case insensitivity for instance a word named "ComPuTER" should be found by typing the word "MpUT"?

Comment: Man....you've gotta mark a few of your answers as answers, at least some of them must have been helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `contains`:

```
var query = from t in tbl
            where t.ToUpper().Contains(input.ToUpper())
            select t;
```

I used ToUpper to ensure that the table and the source are the same case, so that "Coo" will match "cookies"

There's also a Like method in SQLMethods, but I have not used this...

```
var query = from t in tbl
            where SqlMethods.Like(t, "%"+input+"%")
            select t;
```

(See more here: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/16/linq-to-sql-like-operator.aspx)

Comment: Note that for anything beyond trivial numbers of items in tbl, this gets stupidly inefficient, very quickly. If you're searching lots of stuff, use the right tool for the job (and linq-to-objects isn't it).

Comment: Good call on `SqlMethods` thought it feels a little bit like leaking SQL through abstraction layers.  You may also not need to do a call to `ToUpper` if SQL server isn't configured to be case sensitive.

Comment: @R0MANARMY: I don't like it either, but it's easier to read than the other one (IMO). Also, I *think* (but don't want to promise) that using the `SqlMethods.Like` comes with case-insensitive search.

Comment: @Mark: You're might be right. I guess OP will decide if this really is best for what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
var cookies = (from t in tbl where t.Contains("oOK") select t);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using your values. Try it out in LinqPad. Doesn't really use any of the power of Linq though and you'll want to watch it for very large sources.

```
string[] words1 = {"cookies", "lasagna", "steak"};

string searchTerm1 = "Coo";
var matches1 = words1.Where (w => w.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(searchTerm1.ToLowerInvariant()));
Console.WriteLine(matches1.Count().ToString());

string searchTerm2 = "oOk";
var matches2 = words1.Where (w => w.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(searchTerm2.ToLowerInvariant()));
Console.WriteLine(matches2.Count().ToString());

List<string> words2 = new List<string>();
words2.AddRange(new string[] {"abacus", "ComPuTER", "coffee maker"});

string searchTerm3 = "MpUT";
var matches3 = words2.Where (w => w.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(searchTerm3.ToLowerInvariant()));
Console.WriteLine(matches3.Count().ToString());
```